# Enable Component based on the route url

Tags: angular, typescript

How to enable a particular component based on the route url,

I have a component as follows which is in the master page

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-7">
 <headerBar  ></headerBar>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
   <fd-login></fd-login>
</div>
```

in this state app url shows as follows,

```
http://localhost:3000/en/search
```

i want to hide the header bar to appear only when the app is in other states than the above, how can i check it in html using a ngIf or is there an alternate way?

Comment: That's usually what the router does.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i dont get it

Comment: whats wrong with the question? so many downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to router events and then set a property depending on the URL:

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events
  .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .forEach(e => console.log(e.url);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@GünterZöchbauer is trying to say, that you need something like this.

After creating a main app component, link an html file to that component with a router outlet.

```
<div class="container">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Then in your router config file list the components and the different paths.

```
export const rootRouterConfig = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeSectionComponent},
  {path: 'search', component: SearchSectionComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginSectionComponent},
];
```

Then import this into your main module along with your app component.

This will allow you to map 1 component to 1 state giving you the desired result of not showing the other components.

Please proceed to the Angular website as they have it explained in greater detail than what I have shown here. They have a tutorial that you can read, code along with in order to learn how routing works.

Here is a link to the Angular 2 architecture: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html